# How can I programmatically determine the pass percentage for karate features/scenarios after running a test suite?

Tags: karate

In our CI/CD pipeline setup using GitLab, how can I automate the process of assessing the pass percentage of Karate features/scenarios/tests following the execution of a test suite? This assessment is crucial for making decisions regarding whether to proceed with subsequent stages of the pipeline, such as deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally teams expect all 100% tests to pass else the build fails, and that's [how it works today](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#junit-5-parallel-execution), example below.

```
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:").parallel(5);
    assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
```

Java teams can use the same `Runner` API and call [more methods on the `Results` object](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.0/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Results.java#L174) to get total passed and total failed scenarios etc. The rest is up to you and typically JUnit.